# How to import npm module mark.js to use in chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I tried importing module [mark.js](https://markjs.io) into chrome extension.
I've tried modifing code from the chrome tutorial. This is what I tried, most recently:

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Highlight",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Highlight some text",
  "permissions": ["activeTab", "declarativeContent", "storage"],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*.com/*"],
      "js": ["mark.js"]
    }
  ],
  "page_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

popup.js (which is invoked in popup.html)

```
let changeColor = document.getElementById('changeColor');

changeColor.onclick = function(element) {
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(
      tabs[0].id,
      {code: 'var context = document.querySelector(".article-body-component"); var instance = new Mark(context); instance.mark("grows");'});
  });
};
```

When I clicked the button on a site, I get error `Uncaught ReferenceError: Mark is not defined at <anonymous>:1:100`

Is this something wrong with how I require npm module or perphaps I took a wrong file? I installed npm module using `npm install mark.js` and then copies a file from `npm_modules/mark.js/dist/mark.js`.

Comment: Remove "content_scripts" section entirely and instead use two nested executeScript: the first one for mark.js, the second one (inside the callback of the first one) for your code.

Answer (score 0):

Following [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53353336/how-to-import-npm-module-mark-js-to-use-in-chrome-extension#comment93594304_53353336), I made the following changes and it works!

```
let changeColor = document.getElementById('changeColor');

changeColor.onclick = function(element) {
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "mark.js" }, function() {
      chrome.tabs.executeScript(
        tabs[0].id,
        {code: 'var context = document.querySelector(".article-body-component"); var instance = new Mark(context); instance.mark("grows");'});
    })
  });
};
```